# Line after the table shows up on previous page

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[b]{1\linewidth}\centering
\begin{tabular}{l l c l | l l c c}
One & Two  &  Three  &  Four  &  Five  &  Six  &  Seven  &  Eight\\
One & Two  &  Three  &  Four  &  Five  &  Six  &  Seven  &  Eight\\
One & Two  &  Three  &  Four  &  Five  &  Six  &  Seven  &  Eight\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Derivation Table}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

This line after the table is showing up on the previous page. How to display it after the table in a new line

Comment: A `table` is a floating object. It does not appear at the exact place you put it in the source code but rather at the next best position. This does not have any impact on the surrounding text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it this way.

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l l c l | l l c c}
One & Two  &  Three  &  Four  &  Five  &  Six  &  Seven  &  Eight\\
One & Two  &  Three  &  Four  &  Five  &  Six  &  Seven  &  Eight\\
One & Two  &  Three  &  Four  &  Five  &  Six  &  Seven  &  Eight\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Derivation Table}
\end{table}
```

and by the way: The minipage is not needed.

Comment: Tried by taking the minipage out but still the last line shows up on the previous page rather than below the table

Comment: then _replace_ the `figure` environment with a `minipage` one and use `captionof{figure}{...}`, which needs package `caption` or `capt-of`